# If statement is working but I dont know why | React.js + styled-Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to make a plus symbol ("+") with two `<div>`s. If you click on the parent container you toggle the `viability` of the `<Vertical />` div from `true` to `false` (viable to not-viable) so it becomes a minus ("-").
I have the following code and it works but I don't know why:

```
        function Nav() {
            const [visability, setVisability] = useState(true);  /* <--it first renders "+", changes to "-"
            const changeVisability = () => {
                setVisability(!visability)
                console.log("Visability=", visability);
            };
    
    return (
        <Button onClick={changeVisability}>
            <ListItemsNoRightSpace>More</ListItemsNoRightSpace>
              <Plus>
                 <Horizontal />
                 {visability ? (<Vertical />) : (<Vertical />, <Horizontal />)}
              </Plus>
         </Button>    
    )
    };

const Plus = styled.div`
display: block;
grid-column: 1;
grid-row: 1;
position: relative;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
margin-left: -2px;
`
const Horizontal = styled.div`
position: absolute;
top: 14px;
left: 9px;
width: 12px;
height: 2px;
background-color: black;
`

const Vertical = styled.div`
position: absolute;
left: 14px;
top: 9px;
width: 2px;
height: 12px;
background-color: black;
`


    /* and why does this not work? 
     <Plus>
         <Horizontal />
         {visability ? (<Vertical />) : ()}  // in other words: () = "render nothing"
     </Plus>
    */
```

or is there a better way to write this function?

[image: More+]
[image: More-]
from `true` to `false` (Mehr = More in German)

Comment: `()` does not mean "render nothing", it is a syntax error.

Comment: I noticed that too and changed it to "null".

Comment: Similarly, `(<Vertical />, <Horizontal />)` is incorrect.

Comment: But is it possible to write it in one line of code?

Comment: What does "visability" mean?

Comment: And the + and - signs are made out of divs? Why not simply use characters?